# Adding custom styles to elements, without creating new elements

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, css

So Im using the `tiny_mce_before_init` filter to added a few classes to the `wp_editor` and am getting unexpected results. I havent used this before, but from what Im reading and what my peers tell me I should be able to apply classes to elements in the editor directly, and not creating a wrapper element.

So I have this:

```
 $new_styles = array(
        array(
            'title' => __( 'Custom Styles', 'title' ),
                          array(
                'title'     => __('Table Header','kjd'),
                'classes'   => 'table-header',
                'wrapper'   => true
            ),
            array(
                'title'     => __('Table Subheader','kjd'),
                'classes'   => 'table-subheader',
                'wrapper'   => true
            )....
```

From what I understand, both `'inline'` and `'block'` are optional and the `'wrapper'=>true` argument will apply the class to the selected element, and not wrap it in whatever. But no matter which options I apply (like `'wrapper'=>false`, or `'block' => 'td'` ) work. Anyway, Im told that this funcationality changed in WP 3.9

My goal is to apply some classes to table cells so that when my client copies and pastes in a table, they can style it appropriately. They would click a cell and apply the style to said cell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the wrapper should be a problem, as long as the classes of the TD-elements are unique. Did you check the CSS output using FireBug (or Chrome Developer)? The client should be able to style it, like so

```
.tinymce .table .table-header td {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this still doesn't work how I was led to believe, but I've opted for using the "selector" argument to make specific rules for my tables. so using `"selector" => "td"` i was able to appropriately target the table cells.